# Importing model in utils.py causes ImproperlyConfigured

Tags: python, django

I have created a file called `utils.py` in my Django app, where I keep random classes or functions that do something.
I have run into an issue, where I can't import any model in `utils.py` file.
I have models called `User` which inherit from `AbstractUser` and it's been said to Django by: `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'main.User'`

I have also a model called `Project`.
Whenever I type `from main.models import Project` or `User` in `utils.py` I get `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'main.User' that has not been installed`

Of course main is in installed apps in settings.
I have solved this before by using `get_user_model()` for `User`, but there is no such a function to get a `Project`.

How to solve this problem? Am I missing something?

Comment: It sounds like you have a circular import. We can't tell where it is because you haven't shown the code or the full traceback. In general, try to restructure your code so that models imports from utils and utils does not import from models, or vice versa.

Comment: @Alasdair that would be it. Thanks, problem solved. I've been importing mixin from utils in model and in utils I've been importing model from models that inherited mixin.

Answer (score 0):

Circular import. I've been importing mixin from `utils` in model and in `utils` I've been importing model from `models` that inherited mixin.